# Domain Name Split to Subnet DD-WRT

Tags: nat, dd-wrt

I an trying to setup a server system at home because I recently switched ISP's.

I own the vrakiver.net domain name through the register.com registrar.
My ISP provides a static IP to my DD-WRT router.
I have 2 computers setup with static IP's:

1st: "server" with IP 192.168.1.102

2nd: "g5" with IP 192.168.1.100

I from within the LAN I can connect to either with server.local or g5.local or at their respective IP's.

I Would Like to set up the system so that I can use g5.vrakiver.net from anywhere in the world to access "g5" and server.vrakiver.net to access "server"

Port forwarding isn't going to cut it, because I need access to all the ports of both devices. (But not necessarily at  the same time)

I read something somewhere about some systems asking what domain the user was directed from and then deciding where to route based on that.

*** I Think this should be physically posible, beacuse it would be so easy on IPv6, just set the domain record to each hosts publicly accessible IP.***

Thanks in advance for any advice on this you can give.

Comment: Do you have a public IPV6?

Comment: No, But I have Experimented with tunnels. however I doubt my clients have access to the ipv6 internet yet, so that wouldn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid what you're trying to achieve is not possible.

Your clients will first resolve `server.vrakiver.net` or `g5.vrakiver.net` before contacting your router.
As the resolution yields the same IP adress, your router has no way to know which name has been used.

Comment: Yes, but some where I remember reading that Http 1.1 or something supported the client telling the server where it was directed from

Comment: You're talking about Virtual Hosting. This works because the request header contains the hostname. Most protocols don't contain any hostname info in their payload.

Comment: Do you want to do just plain HTTP?

Comment: Ok yeah... That makes sense... So what about a tunnel or ipencap. Would that be able to give my second server it's own IP? Then it could have its own domain. Does anyone know what software ( Ubuntu) would be able to do this?

Comment: What you're trying to host on these machines? Are you expecting to get an additional public IP without paying extra money?